# Export Linux Desktop to others via Web

Tags: linux, browser, remote-desktop, vnc

Is there a way to show other people my Linux Desktop via web?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and have a web server with full root access.

I searched the web and found vnc, but the view-client needs Java which is very uncommon in modern web browsers.

Is there a way to do this without Java/Flash client?

**Update**

- The web client (view part) should any modern browser (IE9 or newer). Without the need to install a plugin.
- The web client is readonly: he just sees the linux desktop, but can't interact.
- Of course I know that you need some tool on the desktop to export it.

Comment: I noticed that Skype which has a screen-sharing option on Windows has a version for Linux - http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/

Comment: Java is very uncommon?

Comment: @user1301428 Modern web applications don't use Java on the client. That's my point of view. Server side is a different topic of course.

Answer (score 2):

Just stream it via your favorite streaming service.
It'll be read-only of course.

Software like OpenBroadcaster and the streaming service justin.tv could help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need for some reason to host this service yourself. However if you do not, you could easily use Google hangouts to share your desktop with anyone through their web browser. You don't need to install anything except Google Chrome with the Hangouts extension.

Comment: I updated my requirements: The web client (view part) should be any modern web browser. For me this means IE9 or newer. Can IE9 view the desktop exported via google hangouts?